# Branch onInitFinished not called after activity recreated

Tags: android, branch.io

I initialize the Branch instance as indicated by the Branch guide.

In my launcher activity, I have the following:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
            ...
```

It works fine when the user first opens the app. However, if the user backs out of the app, and then re-launches the app (so the app stays in memory; ie: the Application class onCreate is NOT called again), then things don't work as expected. The launcher activity is recreated and `onStart` is called, but the `onInitFinished` is never called again.

Any ideas on how to handle this situation?

Note: I'm using the latest branch release:

```
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is already inited. You are expecting a singleton (which means there is only one instance in an application scope) to be re-inited.

I have checked the source and followed the code, you can see the control in [Branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Branch-SDK/src/io/branch/referral/Branch.java) at line 1196.

Good luck

Comment: Thx. Based on that code, the `onInitFinished` should be called even if the session is initialized.

Comment: I thought its already being called once when you said it worked fine for the first time app launched. If its never called there should be credentials or configration issues.

Comment: Do you call another function to init SDK? We may need to check documentation for implementation.

Comment: If you have Branch configured correctly, your Activity mode should be `singleTask` i.e. there will be only one instance of the Activity at any given point in time. Hence, if you click on another Branch link with the App backgrounded or if you reopen the App by clicking the App icon, the `initSession` will not be called again.